# Is there any tool that gives the percentage occupied by an area in an image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, software-recommendation

Is there any tool that gives the percentage occupied by an area in a image?

Given the following image:

[image]

Is there any kind of tool I can use to know the width in percent of the green and blue areas?

So, if the green rectangle is 30% wide and the blue one is 70%, how can I know that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to automate the process for 100s of images, or just get an actual value for this single case?

Comment: In the world of responsive design I can see such a tool being kind of useful. I'm not aware of such a tool though. So that leaves figuring out the pixels of the desired area, the pixels of the wider component its a part of, and then using math to figure out the percentages.

Comment: Have you tried the [measure tool](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-measure.html)? It's a linear measure, but you can use it to calculate the percent. In alternative you can measure the area of a selection with the pixel count in [histogram dialog](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-histogram-dialog.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Photoshop is an option, it can be a viable solution to show the outer dimensions of selected area.

Activate Wand instrument (shortcut 'w') (leave settings to default, since rectangles are sharp and contrast), show info panel (shortcut F8).

[image]

Set 'Ruler Units' to 'Percent' in Info panel's options (duplicates the setting in Preferences / Rulers & Units but easier to reach).

[image]
[image]